# Flutter ios build fails Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

I'm trying to build a flutter app for ios. The simulator runs fine, but I cannot build to test on a phone.

The problem occurs when I try to install url_launcher, without it everything works fine. I already tried reinstalling the pods, creating a project from scratch, but nothing seems to work. I also tried switching back to the legacy build system of Xcode, but still nothing

this is the error code

```
Stripped /Users/matteo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fagvhlbapfiuygdkuldipojcrkxy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Eat o'clock.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter of architectures: x86_64 armv7
Code Signing /Users/matteo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fagvhlbapfiuygdkuldipojcrkxy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Eat o'clock.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework with Identity Apple Development: mgassend@gmail.com (WYPNXJUKW6)
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign A2192773669C062BD98ECAE7CEB4F7FF42D3B25C  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/matteo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fagvhlbapfiuygdkuldipojcrkxy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Eat o'clock.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework'
/Users/matteo/foodfighter/mobile3/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh: eval: line 131: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
```

Have any of you ever experienced something like this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem, I found out, was due to the app's name (Eat o'clock). Since the command is a string that uses ' ' as separators for a variable at the end of the script, this was causing an error. Hope this can help someone in my same situation